# How can I get a numerical value from a function?

Tags: function-construction, physics

I am a Mathematica beginner working on a problem in the area of quantum mechanics. I adapted 
[this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/QuantumWellExplorer/) source code to work with the problem I'm trying to solve. At present, the graphics produced by the code tell me most of what I need to know, but I would like to know how to get Mathematica to output the numerical expression for the wavefunction `ψ[x]`.

If someone can take a look at the source code I linked (my own code is quite similar save for a few numerical modifications) and illuminate how to get a numerical expression for `ψ`, I'd be quite grateful.

I am sure there is a simple solution to this that my lack of Mathematica knowledge is preventing me from seeing. My apologies if this seems like a stupid question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Sorry about not properly linking the cross post. I did post this same question to the Wolfram forums, linked [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1508874?p_p_auth=VPYAqll2).

Comment: Same question posted on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1508874)

Comment: @Sebastian Please see https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/368/4999

Comment: This is outdated code. Maybe it would be better to write a new one?